# Cant view webcam after being ran once. C#

Tags: c#, video, reference, webcam

the title may sound confusing but ill explain it better here. Im making a program which displays the webcam capture in a picturebox using the "easy web cam" external reference. If i turn on my computer, go into VS, open the project and run, it will work, displaying my webcam capture. If i stop the program and then run it again, when i try to display it, i get a popup asking me to select a video source, none of the options is even my webcam and then another popup will appear saying

"An error ocurred while capturing the video image. The video capture will now be terminated.

Object reference not set to ann instance of an object"

The only thing i can think of is that the first time its setting up the camera but when i close it im not turning it off properly so when i run it again, it wont work. anyway heres the relevant code, bare in mind if answering, im not that experienced when coding so sometimes you might have to spell stuff out

```
using WebCam_Capture;

namespace WindowsWebRef
{
public partial class Frm_Main : Form
{
    public Frm_Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    WebCam webcam;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webcam.Start();
    }

    private void Frm_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webcam = new WebCam();
        webcam.InitializeWebCam(ref WebCamIMG);
    }
```

And the webcam class...

```
    class WebCam
{
    private WebCamCapture webcam;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox _FrameImage;
    private int FrameNumber = 30;
    public void InitializeWebCam(ref System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox ImageControl)
    {
        webcam = new WebCamCapture();
        webcam.FrameNumber = ((ulong)(0ul));
        webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
        webcam.ImageCaptured += new WebCamCapture.WebCamEventHandler(webcam_ImageCaptured);
        _FrameImage = ImageControl;
    }

    void webcam_ImageCaptured(object source, WebcamEventArgs e)
    {
        _FrameImage.Image = e.WebCamImage;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
        webcam.Start(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer and be sure to add in `webcam.Stop();` otherwise your program will hold on to the webcam and make it unavailable to use in any other application (or a different instance of the program.)